# css menu with jquery

Tags: jquery

Cant get this script to work with my menu really have tried everything any ideas? The divs has a background image which is on hover then jquery does the on click release li menu... is the hover function messing it up?

```
<div class="top_menu">
    <div class="top_menu_menub">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li class="sub">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Control Center</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">APEC Trinity</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">APEC Living</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">APEC Energy</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>​
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('li').click(function(e) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var ulId = $this.attr("href");
            var clicked_menu_is_visible = $this.parent().find("ul" + ulId).filter(':visible').length > 0;
            var visible_uls = $this.parent().find("ul").filter(':visible');
            if (visible_uls.length === 0) { //no menus showing - just show clicked menu 
                $ul = $this.parent().find("ul" + ulId);
                $ul.slideToggle('medium');
            }
            else { //close open menus (should only be one open) then open clicked menu
                //via callback 
                $this.parent().find("ul").filter(':visible').slideUp("medium", function() {
                    $ul = $this.parent().find("ul" + ulId);
                    //open clicked menu - unless menu was already open when clicked
                    if (!clicked_menu_is_visible) {
                        $ul.slideToggle('medium');
                    }
                });
            }
            console.log($(this).children()[0].innerText);
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    });
});​
```

CSS:

```
.top_menu_menub {
    padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #aaa;
    background-image: url(../images/apecbuttona.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 8px 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 24px;
}
#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: solid 1px#eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#menu li {
    float: left;
    margin: 1px 1px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999
}
#menu li.sub {
    width: 200px;
    height: 16px;
    padding: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#menu li.sub:hover {
    color: #00CCFF;
    background-image: url(../images/apecbutton.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 8px 0px;
    height: 24px;
}
#menu li a {
    display: block;
    color: #999;
    font-family:arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:23px;
    width:107px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight:100;
    border-bottom: 1px solid # eee;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
#menu li a:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #4FA4F9;
}
#menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9800px;
    width: 115px;
}
#menu li.click {
}
#menu li.click ul {
    left: 12px;
    top: 22px;
    background: #fff;
}
/* the background image is for IE7 */

​
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle (test case) in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bLmwm/   did notice i prob need to change href to look for a dic instead? oringanally the target was (a xxxx)

Comment: Updated fiddle with better code indentation: http://jsfiddle.net/bLmwm/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your click handler is capturing the click event for `<li class="sub">`. I don't know if that's what you want, but it has the side-effect of ensuring `$this.attr("href")` consistently returning `undefined` as the `li` element lacks that attribute.

This leads to the problem of `var ulId` being undefined, which in turn leads to the problem of `$ul` always being an empty jQuery object, so nothing else happens.

Also, your CSS leads to everything being initially not visible or parked `9800px` offscreen to the left. Did you mean for something to be visible initially so the user knows where to click or to hover?

Please clarify in your question the behavior you are expecting.

**UPDATE:**

Per the clarification, below is your jQuery code modified to do what you want:

```
$(function() {
    var toggleMenu = function(e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            ulId = $this.attr("href") || $this.find('a').attr("href"),
            $ul = $this.parents("ul").filter("ul#" + ulId), //cache query
            $all = $("ul#menu ul"), //cache query
            clicked_menu_is_visible = $ul.is(':visible'), //changed .filter to .is
            visible_uls = $all.is(':visible'); //changed .filter to .is
        if (!visible_uls) { //no menus showing - just show clicked menu 
            $ul.slideToggle('medium');
        }
        else { //close open menus (should only be one open) then open clicked menu via callback
            $all.filter(':visible').slideUp("medium", function() {
                //open clicked menu - unless menu was already open when clicked
                if (!clicked_menu_is_visible) {
                    $ul.slideToggle('medium');
                }
            });
        }
        console.log('hideMenu triggered');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div.top_menu_menub').click(function(e) {
            $('ul#menu ul').show('medium');
            console.log('div clicked');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
        $('li.sub li, ul#menu a').click(toggleMenu);
        $('ul#menu ul').mouseleave(toggleMenu);
    });
});​
```

This works with your HTML structure and CSS. [Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bLmwm/8/).

As a side note, I would write it instead as the following:

```
$(function() {
    var toggleMenu = function(e) {
        var self = $(this),
            elemType = self[0].tagName.toLowerCase(),
            //get caller
            menu = null;
        if (elemType === 'a') {
            //anchor clicked, nav back to containing ul
            menu = self.parents('ul').not('ul#menu');
        } else if (elemType === 'ul') {
            //mouseleft ul, ergo menu is this.
            menu = self;
        }
        if (menu) {
            menu.hide('medium');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div.top_menu_menub').click(function(e) {
            $('ul#menu ul').show('medium');
            console.log('div clicked');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
        $('ul#menu a').click(toggleMenu);
        $('ul#menu ul').mouseleave(toggleMenu);
    });
});​
```

This also works with your HTML structure. [Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bLmwm/7/).

Comment: thanks for replying... Once clicking the div top_menu_menub(which has a hover background) i would like the menu to drop once clicked with a toggle effect. once the mouse leaves the menu the menu toggles closed.

Comment: i dont require ahref lookup. but finding hard to tag to the div.

Comment: @DavidWalter: Sorry about the delay. Updated answer with working fiddles. Hope this helps.

Comment: wow thank you sir so muc!!!! PETE YOUR A STAR! gave up and just found your reply! thank u thank u!

Comment: thanks again works a treat is it simple enough to make it slide down instead of toggle

Comment: and should i run another script to stop the div from highlighting on first click?

Comment: @DavidWalter: The menu already slides out (right and down), I merely named the function `toggleMenu`. Also, which `div` highlights on first click? (I'm not seeing what you're referring to in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bLmwm/7/).